Permutation matrix as sum of orthogonal unit vectors
Let $P\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Permutation matrix that exchanges a pair of rows of indeces $1\leq p, q\leq n$. Is there any formula to parameterise $P$ as function of an elementary vector $e_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$, whose $j$-th element is $1$, if $i=j$, and $0$, if $i\neq j$?
I have noticed that:
$P=I_n-e_p e_p^T-e_q e_q^T+e_p e_q^T+e_q e_p^T$
Then, defining the set of integers $\mathcal{I}=\{ p, q \}$:
$P=I_n -\sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}} e_i e_i^T+\sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}, j\in\mathcal{I}/i} e_i e_j^T$
Is there a more general or compact formula?

$$
I - (e_p - e_q)(e_p - e_q)^T
$$
